# error starting rails app with mongrel on wndows xp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-xp, mongrel

I am trying to launch a rails application with mongrel on windows xp.

I believe the following error is version-specific but cannot pinpoint exactly what is missing (a gem overlooked perhaps or an incompatible version?)

My ruby version
C:\ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25) [i386-mingw32]

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.4.rc1, 3.0.3, 2.2.3)
actionpack (3.0.4.rc1, 3.0.3, 2.2.3)
activemodel (3.0.4.rc1, 3.0.3)
activerecord (3.0.4.rc1, 3.0.3, 2.2.3)
activeresource (3.0.4.rc1, 3.0.3, 2.2.3)
activesupport (3.0.4.rc1, 3.0.3, 2.2.3)
arel (2.0.7)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.10)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
erubis (2.6.6)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.15)
mime-types (1.16)
minitest (1.6.0)
mongrel (1.2.0.pre2 x86-mingw32, 1.1.5 x86-mingw32)
mongrel_service (0.4.0)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.4.rc1, 3.0.3, 2.2.3)
railties (3.0.4.rc1, 3.0.3)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (2.5.8)
rubygems-update (1.5.0)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.24)

In my working directory I attempt to start the app with this command:

```
mongrel_rails start -e development -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000
```

The error is:
C:\myApp>mongrel_rails start -e development -a 127.0.0.1 -p 3000
** Starting Mongrel listening at 127.0.0.1:3000
** Starting Rails with development environment...

> :29:in `require': no such file to load--
>
>   C:/myApp/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer (LoadError)
>
>           from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require'
>           from C:/myApp/config/boot.rb:45:in `load_initializer'
>
>           from C:/myApp/config/boot.rb:38:in`run'
>           from C:/myApp/config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
>
>           from C:/myApp/config/boot.rb:109:in`'
>           from :29:in `require'
>
>           from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require'
>           from C:/myApp/config/environment.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
>
>           from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require'
>           from :29:in `require'
>
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/
>   lib/mongrel/rails.rb:147:in`rails'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/
>   bin/mongrel_rails:116:in `block (2 levels) in run'
>
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/
>   lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in`call'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/
>   lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `listener'
>
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/
>   bin/mongrel_rails:102:in`block in run'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/
>   lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `call'
>
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/
>   lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in`initialize'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/
>   bin/mongrel_rails:86:in `new'
>
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/
>   bin/mongrel_rails:86:in`run'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/
>   lib/mongrel/command.rb:210:in `run'
>
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/
>   bin/mongrel_rails:282:in`'
>           from C:/Ruby192/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
>
>           from C:/Ruby192/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in`'

Any ideas or direction on how to about resolving this will much appreciated.If I am missing a file or gem, or if it is a version conflict, it is not clear which one is it.

Also given the different versions on the same gem installed, how could I start the rails app on mongrel specifying exactly what versions I want to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

would you please paste the contents of your gem file?

make sure you have:

```
gem 'mongrel', '>= 1.2.0.pre2'
```

then run `bundle install` to update your gem.

run server: `rails server mongrel`